# pandas: boolean indexing using a list of boolean series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean

Say you have a list of pandas Series objects, each series being of boolean `dtype`:

```
boolean_series_list = [s1, s2, s3, ..., sn]
```

You have another series `s` which has the same index as all the boolean series in `boolean_series_list`, and you want to index it to return only values for which `True` appears at the corresponding index of *any* of the series in `boolean_series_list`. How do you do that?

I know the `|` operator can be used to combine such series:

```
s[s1|s2]
```

but how do you do this for the entire list of such series without manually rolling it out into `s[s1|s2|s3|...|sn]`? Something like:

```
cond = boolean_series_list[0]
for series in boolean_series_list[1:]:
    cond = cond | series
s[cond]
```

works, but it seems relatively clunky considering the typically neat high-level interface tha Pandas provides for interacting with Boolean series, like use of the boolean operator `|` and others in the first place, even though Series objects aren't actual booleans. With actual booleans in Python, you can just use the built-in `any()` function, but `any(boolean_series_list)` returns:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

so is there any neat equivalent to `any()` for Pandas objects?

Similar question for the `&` operator, which for actual booleans is served by the built-in `all()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first gather all the boolean series into one dataframe, then use `any` to aggregate the conditions into one series:

```
cond = pd.concat(boolean_series_list, axis=1).any(axis=1)
s[cond]
```

To get the equivalent of using chained `&` operators you can similarly use `all` instead of `any`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'key1': True, 'key2': False},
    {'key1': False, 'key2': True},
    {'key1': True, 'key2': True},
    {'key1': False, 'key2': False},
    {'key1': False, 'key2': True}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
df[(df['key1']==True) & (df['key2']==True)]

df_indexed = df[(df['key1']==True) & (df['key2']==True)]
```

Output:

```
    key1    key2
  2 True    True
```